# ADO parameter query is inserting the same data into each row

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2010, ado

I have the following code to enter several rows of excel data into a microsoft Access database. The code appears to be working and data is being written to the database. The only problem is, only the first row of data is being entered, several times!

[image: foo]

Here is my code:

```
Sub AddToDB()
Dim adoConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim adoComm As ADODB.Command
Dim RecordRow As Long
Dim TheProduct As String, TheQuantity As String, ThePrice As Double
Dim Location As String, TheTime As Date, SaleNumber As Integer

Set adoConn = GetConnectionTWO
Set adoComm = New ADODB.Command
Lastrow = Sold.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Location = Frontsheet.Range("M3").Value

        With adoComm
                Set .ActiveConnection = adoConn

                    For RecordRow = 2 To Lastrow

                            SaleNumber = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 1).Value
                            TheTime = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 5).Value
                            TheProduct = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 2).Value
                            TheQuantity = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 3).Value
                            ThePrice = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 4).Value

                            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Sales([SaleNo],[Time],[Location],[Product],[Quantity],[Price]) " & _
                                          "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)"

                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adInteger, Value:=SaleNumber)
                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adDate, Value:=TheTime)
                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=255, Value:=Location)
                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=255, Value:=TheProduct)
                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adVarWChar, Size:=255, Value:=TheQuantity)
                            .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter(Type:=adDouble, Value:=ThePrice)

                            .Execute

                    Next RecordRow    
        End With

            adoConn.Close
End Sub


Function GetConnectionTWO() As ADODB.Connection
    Set GetConnectionTWO = New ADODB.Connection
    GetConnectionTWO.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" &  PathToDatabaseTWO & ";"
End Function

Function PathToDatabaseTWO() As String
PathToDatabaseTWO = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "kimpostwo.accdb"
End Function
```

I thought the "For - Next" loop i have would move to the next row, and when i step through the code in the excel VBA editor, i can see the data changing.

Ive tried moving the .commandtext line before and after the .parameter.append lines but still no change.

I'm very new to using ADO and would appreciate a pointer on what i need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of addind all parameters again and again in the for-loop try to create the named parameter only once and change its value only before Excecute() is called. Example for 'SaleNumber':

```
With adoComm
    Set .ActiveConnection = adoConn
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Sales([SaleNo]) VALUES(?)"
    .Parameters.Append adoComm.CreateParameter("SaleNumber", Type:=adInteger)

    For RecordRow = 2 To Lastrow

        SaleNumber = Sold.Cells(RecordRow, 1).Value

        .Parameters("SaleNumber").Value = SaleNumber
        .Execute

    Next RecordRow
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Gord! it worked after including your suggestion above! :) i now have seven different entries in the database based on my example above.Another thing just occurred to me. Is it possible to check if each of the lines already exists in the database, and if so either overwrite it or skip it? For each line the unique information would be a combination of the salenumber and date.The primary key in the database is currently an autoincrementing field (ID), which i would prefer to keep unchanged if possible. many thanks

Comment: Well I am not Gord :-) but anyway I am happy it helped! Please accept my answer if you are satisfied with it. To check if data exist in table is possible, just execute 'SELECT SaleNo, Time FROM Sales WHERE ...' and if it returns something then do not execute INSERT but do something else (UPDATE or ignore).

Comment: Sorry @dee! :) thanks and i have accepted it. Will try out your suggestion. cheers